# Access an offline device

Tags: networking

I have a problem. My internet service goes out every few weeks (thank you Time Warner) and I want to be able to reboot my modem remotely.

So how do I access my router if it's down? Or access a raspberry pi that would reboot the modem.

Assume I can get the password from my neighbor for his wifi.  Can anyone lead me down the right path to solving this solution

This might be the wrong forum for this. (Tried the Raspberry Pi forum first). Hoping that someone here might have an idea.

MODS: will take this down if too off-topic

Comment: Are you using your own modem? Maybe the problem is that their modem just stinks.

Comment: Off topic here. VtC'ed to migrate to SU.

Comment: @NeilSmithline - I  was wondering about that. I thought that part of the advantage of using their modem was that they would be able to reboot the machine remotely.

Comment: @Polynomial - how do I migrate it over?

Comment: Can't you just use the raspberry to monitor the modem, and reboot it when it goes sour? - No need for remote access when you got robots to do your bidding.

Comment: @Polynomial - was thinking about something like that: the raspberry pings the modem every 30 seconds if it doesn't get a response fox "x" times then it cycles on a powerstrip

Comment: @Mayo Vote to close and the select the off topic and then migrate to option

Comment: As for solution, I'd go for an IP-enabled power switch. You'll find plenty of models that also monitors your connection and automatically cycle the power whenever a connection failure is detected.